# Inserting into a number string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, insert

Have the function DashInsert(num) insert dashes ('-') between each two odd numbers in num. For example: if num is 454793 the output should be 4547-9-3. Don't count zero as an odd number. 
Here is my code (not working). When I run it, I get the same response as an infinite loop where I have to kill the page but I can't see why. I know there are ways to do this by keeping it as a string but now I'm wondering why my way isn't working. Thanks...

```
function DashInsert(num) {  
  num = num.split("");
  for (i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i - 1] % 2 != 0 && num[i] % 2 != 0) {
      num.splice(i, 0, "-");
    }
  }
  num = num.join("");
  return num;
}
```

Comment: @A1rPun that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It does, your code could lead to strange behaviour.

Comment: I think it's because there are cases when you use the % operator on dash '-' itself, e.g. right after you splice a dash into the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `num.splice` you are inserting new entries into the array, therefor increasing its length – and that makes the value of `i` “running behind” the increasing length of the array, so the break condition is never met.

And apart from that, on the next iteration after inserting a `-`, `num[i-1]` will be that `-` character, and therefor you are practically trying to check if `'-' % 2 != 0` … that makes little sense as well.

So, when you insert a `-` into the array, you have to increase `i` by one as well – that will a) account for the length of the array having increased by one, and also it will check the next digit *after* the `-` on the next iteration:

```
function DashInsert(num) {  
  num = num.split("");
  for (i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i - 1] % 2 != 0 && num[i] % 2 != 0) {
      num.splice(i, 0, "-");
      i++; // <- this is the IMPORTANT part!
    }
  }
  num = num.join("");
  return num;
}

alert(DashInsert("454793"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/37wA9/

Comment: Does your function only work with strings that are shorter than 20?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was only a left-over from debug measures on why it’s running “endless” – removed.

Answer (score 2):

Once you insert a dash `-`, the `if` statement is checking this `'-'%2 != 0` which is always true and thus inserts another dash, ad infinitum.

Here's one way to do it with `replace` using a regex and function:

```
function DashInsert(n) {
    var f = function(m,i,s) { return m&s[i+1]&1 ? m+'-' : m; };
    return String(n).replace(/\d/g,f);
}

DashInsert(454793) // "4547-9-3"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. He was looking for what's wrong in his code, not an alternate solution. Copy/pasting this after the fact is just plagiarism :)

Comment: @ktm5124 Huh? What's the plagarism? Hover over the edit times to see the time stamps. My edit was at 23:45:04Z and your comment was at 23:45:15Z, **11 seconds later**.

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding a dash, this dash will be processed as a number on the next iteration. You need to forward one step.

```
function DashInsert(num) {  
  var num = num.split("");
  for (var i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
    if ((num[i - 1] % 2 != 0) && (num[i] % 2 != 0)) {
      num.splice(i, 0, "-");
      i++; // This is the only thing that needs changing
    }
  }
  num = num.join("");
  return num;
}
```

Comment: Double checked it again, still works on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are cases when you use the % operator on dash '-' itself, e.g. right after you splice a dash into the array.

You can correct this behavior by using a clone array.

```
function DashInsert(num) {  
  num = num.split("");

  var clone = num.slice(0);
  var offset = 0;

  for (i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i - 1] % 2 != 0 && num[i] % 2 != 0) {
      clone.splice(i + offset, 0, "-");
      offset++;
    }
  }

  return clone.join("");
}

alert(DashInsert("45739"));
```

**Output:** 45-7-3-9

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/262Bf/

Answer (score 0):

To complement the great answers already given, I would like to share an alternative implementation, that doesn't modify arrays in-place:

```
function DashInsert(num) {  
  var characters = num.split("");

  var numbers = characters.map(function(chr) {
    return parseInt(chr, 10);
  });

  var withDashes = numbers.reduce(function(result, current) {
    var lastNumber = result[result.length - 1];

    if(lastNumber == null || current % 2 === 0 || lastNumber % 2 === 0) {
      return result.concat(current);
    } else {
      return result.concat("-", current);
    }
  }, []);

  return withDashes.join("");
}
```

It's longer, but IMHO reveals the intention better, and avoids the original issue.